# Node-js ,MongoDB - Groupby each hour in a day (1-24)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, node-modules

I have a collection where i have sales made in a company with timestamp.
 I need to  get data such that it uses group by for every hour i.e 1am, 2am....

```
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "billNo" : "000000001",
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-16T14:16:00.201Z"),
        "grossAmount" : 1000
    }
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "billNo" : "000000002",
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-15T12:16:00.201Z"),
        "grossAmount" : 10000,

    }
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "billNo" : "000000003",
        "dateTime" : ISODate("2017-11-14T11:16:00.201Z"),
        "grossAmount" : 10000,
    }
```

i need output like

```
     {_id:1am,count:0, grossAmount: 0}
     {_id:2am, count:1,grossAmount: 1000}
     {_id:3am,count:1, grossAmount: 2000}
```

i need for all 24 hours even if the count is 0. Here gross amount is the sum of grossAmount for the particular hour.
Is it possible to do in mongodb queries or i need to work in my node after fetching from mongodb.

Comment: I think that the simplest way is to perform an aggregate with mongodb and fill the holes with node.

Answer (score 0):

> db.test.aggregate({"$group":{"_id":{"$hour":"$dateTime"},count:{$sum:"$count"},grossAmount:{$sum:"$grossAmount"}}})

**Try this**

Comment: This works only for the values which is present in db. i want zero values for the time which is not available.